# Why is a collection whose name starts with an underscore treated differently?

Tags: mongodb

The name of a collection must start with either a letter or an underscore.

Then why does the first one works, while the last two don't? Thanks.

```
> db.getCollection("_20160712").find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57a38e4991c3b3a393e9be2b"), "dimension_id" : 2, "attribute" : "good", "hour" : "20160712_06", "frequency_count" : 100 }
> db._20160712.find()
2016-08-04T14:53:56.963-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] TypeError: db._20160712 is undefined :
@(shell):1:1
> db['_20160712'].stats()
2016-08-04T14:52:43.964-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] TypeError: db._20160712 is undefined :
@(shell):1:1
```

Answer (score 13):

According to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#naming-restrictions)

> If your collection name includes special characters, such as the underscore character, then to access the collection use the db.getCollection() method in the mongo shell or a similar method for your driver.

According to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/#db.getCollection) `db.getCollection(name)` method

> Returns a collection object that is functionally equivalent to using the db.collectionName syntax. The method is useful for a collection **whose name might interact with the shell itself, such as names that begin with _** or that match a database shell method.

So, actually you can access collection with name that includes underscore (**not on the first position**) without `db.getCollection()` method.

Next examples are valid in mongo Shell

```
db.collection_.find();
db.collection_1.find();
```

Only when underscore is on the first position, the only way you can access  collection in mongo Shell is by using `db.getCollection()` method.

It's not treated differently, it's just how mongo Shell works.

Comment: In the second to last paragraph should read db.getCollection() instead of db.getConnection()